# Cannot convert type list.<string> to string error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a controller method that looks like this

```
//cycles through sites in order to populate variables

  foreach (Site s in sites)
            {
                foreach (OffSiteItemDetails d in s.ItemDetails)
                {

                    if (d.itemID != null)
                    {

                        osiItemCost[s.ID] = d.qty * db.Items.Where(x => x.ID == d.itemID).FirstOrDefault().cost(1, false, false);
                        osiLoItemCost[s.ID] += d.qty * db.Items.Where(x => x.ID == d.itemID).FirstOrDefault().cost(1, false, true);

                        osiItemLastCost[s.ID] += db.Items.Where(x => x.ID == d.itemID).FirstOrDefault().cost(d.qty, true, false);

                    }
                 }
             }
```

o it generates a value for each variable for example osiItemCost[s.ID] could equal 0 for one site ID but it could equal 70 for another Site

So I am trying to create a table for each site ID. Currently if I leave it like 
model.OffReportColumns = new List()

It will just keep getting overwritten by the next site Id in the list. So I am trying to assign the list to the sites ID.

```
foreach (Site s in sites)
{

    foreach (OffSiteItemDetails d in s.ItemDetails)
    {

        model.OffReportColumns[s.ID] = new List<string>()
            {
                s.Name,
                "",
                "",
                "Average Cost",
                "",
                "",
                "Average Cost (With labour)"
            };
```

Here is my Model class

```
 public class SummaryReportModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ReportTitle { get; set; }
        public string OffReportTitle { get; set; }
        public List<string> ValuationColumns { get; set; }
        public List<string> OffReportColumns { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> ValuationRows { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> OffReportRows { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> Total { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> OffReporTotal { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> Tital { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> SecondTital { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> osiGrandTotal { get; set; }
    }
```

Where `s.ID` represents a "site ID"

Currently I receive the errors

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'systems.collections.generic.List' to 'string'

However, it works when I remove the [s.ID] so that it looks like this

`model.OffReportColumns = new List<string>()`

Why is the `s.ID` causing an issue?

Comment: ``OffReportColumns`` represent list of string, then ``OffReportColumns[0]`` gives string and not list of string, may be you can change the type ``List<string>`` to ``Dictionary<int, List<string>>`` and ``s.ID`` the key.

Comment: `model.OffReportColumns = new List<List<string>>()`

Answer (score 4):

When you use `model.OffReportColumns[s.ID]` you are referencing the individual string with an index of `s.ID`. When you use `model.OffReportColumns` you are referencing the entire list.

You cannot set `model.OffReportColumns[s.ID]` equal to `new List<string>()` because a `List<string>` is not a `string`

Comment: Thanks for explaining Tyler. Do you have a suggestion as to what I can do to work around this? I want it to generate the list for each siteID in my sites table.

Comment: Its not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Do you need a `List<string>` for every siteId? If thats the case `OffReportColumns` might actually need to be a `List<List<string>>`. If not can you please try to provide a bit more detail/context in your question?

Comment: I updated my question to hopefully provide you with better clarity of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I'm afraid it still isn't quite clear. If you need to store each of those collections in a collection, it would be `List<List<string>>` instead of `List<string>`. When you set `List<string>` equal to your new list in every iteration of the for loop it overwrites it, so you need it use it before that or store it in another collection (thew List of Lists).

Answer (score 0):

Is not really clear what you are trying to do here. It seems that OffReportColumns is a list of strings, and you are trying to add a list a string to a certain index of it.

If you do this

```
model.OffReportColumns.AddRange(new List<String>(){
    s.Name,
    "string test",
    "etc."
})
```

You will add all items of your new list of strings to the end of OffReportColumns.